# Parametric representation of the real branches $\operatorname{W_{0}},\operatorname{W_{-1}}$ of the Lambert W function

Tags: reference-request, logarithms, lambert-w

$\require{begingroup} \begingroup$

$\def\a{\alpha}\def\la{\ln{\a}}\def\e{\mathrm{e}}\def\W{\operatorname{W}}$
$\def\Wp{\operatorname{W_0}}\def\Wm{\operatorname{W_{-1}}}$

For $x\in(-\tfrac1{\mathrm{e}},0)$,
$\a\in(0,1)$
two real branches of the Lambert W function
can be parameterized as follows:

\begin{align}
\Wp(x)&=
\frac{\a\ln\a}{1-\a}
\tag{1}\label{1}
,\\
\Wm(x)&=
\frac{\ln\a}{1-\a}
\tag{2}\label{2}
,\\
x&=\Wp(x)\exp(\Wp(x))
=\Wm(x)\exp(\Wm(x))
\\
&=
\a^{\tfrac a{1-\a}}
\ln\Big(\a^{\tfrac a{1-\a}}\Big)
=
\a^{\tfrac1{1-\a}}
\ln\Big(\a^{\tfrac1{1-\a}}\Big)
.
\end{align}

This parameterization is also consistent with
the values of $\Wp,\Wm$ at $x=0$ and 
$x=-\tfrac1{\mathrm{e}}$:
\begin{align}
\Wp(0)&=
\lim_{\a\to0}\frac{\a\ln\a}{1-\a}=0
,\\
\Wp(-\tfrac1{\mathrm{e}})&=
\lim_{\a\to1}\frac{\a\ln\a}{1-\a}=-1
,\\
\Wm(0)&=
\lim_{\a\to0}\frac{\ln\a}{1-\a}=-\infty
,\\
\Wm(-\tfrac1{\mathrm{e}})&=
\lim_{\a\to1}\frac{\ln\a}{1-\a}=-1
.
\end{align}

For any $x\in(-\tfrac1{\mathrm{e}},0)$
the value of 
corresponding parameter $\a$ is found as

\begin{align}
\a(x)&=\frac{\Wp(x)}{\Wm(x)}
.
\end{align}

A dual form of \eqref{1}-\eqref{2}
can be used for $\a>1$. In this case

\begin{align}
\Wp(x)&=
\frac{\ln\a}{1-\a}
\tag{3}\label{3}
,\\
\Wm(x)&=
\frac{\a\ln\a}{1-\a}
\tag{4}\label{4}
,\\
\a(x)&=\frac{\Wm(x)}{\Wp(x)}
.
\end{align}

One related reference is

D. J. Jeffrey and J. E. Jankowski. "Branch Differences and Lambert W". In: 2014 16th International
Symposium on Symbolic and Numeric Algorithms for Scientific Computing. 
Sept. 2014, pp. 61-65. 
[doi:10.1109/SYNASC.2014.16](https://doi.org/10.1109/SYNASC.2014.16)

where it is shown that
the difference
of branches of the Lambert $\W$ function 
is nontrivial.

Question:
is there any other known references,
where such parameterization is suggested/used?

---

**Edit**
Also, in the fundamental paper

R. M. Corless, G. H. Gonnet, D. E. G. Hare, D. J.Jeffrey,
and D. E. Knuth. On the Lambert W Function.
Advances in Computational
Mathematics, 5:4 (1996) 329-359

there is a closely related example
"Solution of a jet fuel problem",
Eqns. 2.9-2.10, from which such parameterization
can be easily deduced,
but still, the parametric form of $\Wp,\Wm$
is not explicitly mentioned.

$\endgroup$

Comment: Have you looked at [Corless, Gonnet, Hare, Jeffrey and Knuth](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/2458364_On_the_Lambert_W_Function)?

Comment: @Robert Israel: Yes, of course, 
this is a fundamental paper on the Lambert W function,
and there is a related part (Solution of a jet fuel problem),
but I'm looking for the reference, 
where an explicit parameterization of 
$\operatorname{W}_0$ and $\operatorname{W}_{-1}$
is stated/studied.

Comment: Very interesting problem !