# Lower bound for Lambert $W$ function $W_0(x)$

Tags: upper-lower-bounds, lambert-w

I want to find a lower bound for the branch $W_0(x)$ of Lambert $W$ function, for real values in range $-\frac{1}{e} \leq x \leq 0$.  It is apparent that $-1$ is a lower bound for this function in the aforementioned range, but I need a slightly tighter lower bound.

Can anybody offer a better lower bound for this function using only elementary functions?

Comment: In https://arxiv.org/pdf/2004.01115.pdf the following bound is given for the range in question: $$
\sqrt {ex + 1}  - 1 \le W_0 (x).$$

Comment: @JCAA I need a function as a lower bound, not necessarily a constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\require{begingroup} \begingroup$
$\def\e{\mathrm{e}}\def\W{\operatorname{W}}\def\Wp{\operatorname{W_0}}\def\Wm{\operatorname{W_{-1}}}\def\Catalan{\mathsf{Catalan}}$

It looks that

\begin{align} 
f_1(x)&=\frac{1-\sqrt{1-(\e x)^2}}{\e x}
\tag{1}\label{1}
\end{align}

is slightly better lower bound
for $\Wp(x)$ on $x\in[-\tfrac1\e,0]$,
than
\begin{align} 
f_2(x)&=\sqrt{\e x+1}-1
\tag{2}\label{2}
\end{align}

[image]

[image]

$\endgroup$

Comment: Thanks! Do you know any other function as a lower bound which uses $log$ instead of square root? A function consisting of logarithms will be more helpful for me.

Comment: @mahdi: Not at the moment. But, just in case,
both $W_0(x)$ and $x$ 
(as well as $W_{-1}(x)$, not related to this question)
[can be transformed to parametric form](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3233107/122782),
where $W_0(x(a))=\frac{a\ln a}{1-a}$
for $a\in[0,1],\ x(a)\in[-1/\mathrm e,0]$.