# What's wrong with this derivation for a parametric representation of the Lambert-W function?

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

Consider the definition of the Lambert-W function
\begin{align}
We^W=z.
\end{align}
Defining the parameter $\tau$ as follows we find a constant-coefficient second order linear ODE
\begin{align}
(z+e^W)W'_z&=1,\\
z''_{\tau\tau}-2z'_{\tau}+z&=0.\quad[z+e^W=z'_\tau]
\end{align}
This ODE is easily solved, giving our parametric representation
\begin{align}
z=(A+B\tau)e^\tau,\quad
W=\tau+\log(B\tau),
\end{align}
for constants $A$ and $B$. This solution does not work with the original definition, though. Substitution yields
\begin{align}
A+B\tau=B\tau^2+B\tau\log(B\tau),
\end{align}
which is true only for constant $\tau$ or the trivial case of $A=B=0$. The only question with a parametric representation that I've found is [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3233107/parametric-representation-of-the-real-branches-operatornamew-0-operatorna). I'm not sure what is going awry here, could someone point the way?

Comment: How did you derive $z_{\tau\tau}-2z_{\tau}+z=0$ ?

Comment: @user619894 $W=\log(z'-z)$, $\mathrm d_z=1/z'_\tau \mathrm d_\tau$, and $W'_z=(z''_{\tau\tau}-z'_\tau)/(z'_\tau(z'_\tau-z))$